# Implementation of NonNull Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, javac

I thought I delve deeper into older Java Features such as Annotations. I encountered Java 8s Type Annotations which enable us to extend Javas type system.
The most common annotation 'NonNull' or 'NotNull' by IntelliJ's Annotation Libary or the Checkerframework are still a mystery to me. In the Docs I can only find the declaration of the interface, but never how the Annotation processor is realised.
I like to write my own custom Annotations, that checks for specific Types on compiletime, but I dont know how to start.

***Does anybody know how 'NonNull' or 'NotNull' are generally realized within the Annotation processor?***.
Or point me to a resource or documentation that answeres my question?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Slaw couldyou elaborate on that? I already succesfully written a custom annotation making use of java annotation processing API.
I know how to use a Processor, but I dont understand how to ensure Typesafety of nullobjects or <T>Objects

Comment: What do you want to happen exactly? Tools such as SpotBugs don't do anything at runtime, rather they inspect the compiled code for bugs and use certain annotations to help determine what should or should not be allowed. Other tools such as Project Lombok actually modify your code during compilation, I believe, in order to insert code such as null-checks. There's also the option to modify classes at runtime (e.g. through a custom `ClassLoader` or instrumentation).

Comment: Yet other libraries, such as the Bean Validation specification and implementations thereof, possibly use reflection to inspect annotations at runtime in order to control the flow of execution.

Comment: @Slaw if possible 'd like to build onto the annotation processing API, which is nativ to Java. To check at compiletime if a annotated parameter contains a specific subtype.
The NotNull Annotation seems todo something similar. It is able to identify possible null objects at compiletime. And I cant wrap my head around how this is achieved.

Comment: So you want to create a code analyzer that analyzes your code at compile-time using a [`javax.annotation.processing.Processor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html), correct? You may not be able to do much with the `java.compiler` API and might have to drop down into the `jdk.compiler` API. The `java.compiler` API is more geared towards code generation and possible signature validation. Regardless, explaining how to write a source code analyzer is awfully broad—even if I knew enough to give a proper explanation.

Comment: You could try looking at open source tools such as SpotBugs, PMD, Checker Framework, and so on to see how they've implemented the functionality. One tool that might be particularly helpful is Google's [Error Prone](https://github.com/google/error-prone).

Comment: @Slaw I got the same impression. It seems to be mainly used to generate boilerplate code and the Mirror API can only analyse static representations of class files. Thats why I got really interested on how other frameworks handle typesafety at compiletime alas, without refelections.
But as you said it seems to be to broad of a topic, I realized that, when I read the puplications mentioned by mernst.
I will accept the answere and come back to stack with more specific questions.

Comment: I know it is 3 years later but i have my 2 cents to add. Most checking tools do NOT utilize Annotation Processing, but rely on a seperate process to parse and check the sourcecode. Infere from facebook does utilize the java.compiler module api but its not a annotation processor - more a wrapper for javac.

To be precise - `NotNull` has no implementation. There are tools that can read them and send you warnings, but there is no native Java implementation behind `NotNull`. `NotNull` is just a spec - defined in many obscure ways - but just a spec/API - no implementation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned IntelliJ IDEA and the Checker Framework.
The [IDEA source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) and the [Checker Framework source code](https://github.com/mernst/checker-framework/) are available for you to read and learn from.  The Checker Framework manual explains [how to create a new checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#creating-a-checker) and links to [publications](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#publications) that explain more of the theory.

Comment: I already read the "how to create a new checker" section of the framework's documentation. While it is pretty straightforward to make use of the framework im more interested in the technical Implementation and how it works as a concept.

I also looked into the "IDEA source code" but couldnt find the implementation of the "NotNullProcessor". Its a rather big project and just reffering to the sourcecode is not specific enough to answere my question.
But the link to the publications is much appreciated. Although I would like to have a more spot on answere im pretty overwhelmed by the papers

Comment: If you can ask a concrete question, that may elicit a more specific, useful, and concise answer.  If you ask a broad questions, others might not know what you already understand, what you do not, and how you have already tried to find an answer.  Good luck in your quest to better understand the implementations!